# Как правильно построить предложение?

Tags: словообразование

Отделение просит исключить ситуации по не предоставлению в полном объеме файлов с электронными реестрами, сформированными по платежам «Сбербанка России» ОАО, расположенного на территории Краснодарского края или 
Отделение просит исключить ситуации по не предоставлению  файлов с электронными реестрами, сформированными по платежам «Сбербанка России» ОАО, расположенного на территории Краснодарского края,в полном объеме.

Answer (score 2):

Все плохо. Второе хуже.
Правда и в первом варианте надо как минимум поставить одну запятую и *изобрести* слово "непредоставление".

Отделение просит исключить ситуации по ***непредоставлению*** в полном объеме файлов с электронными реестрами, сформированными по платежам «Сбербанка России»***,*** ОАО, расположенного на территории Краснодарского края.

Ну а если править существенно, как Hermit предлагает, то надо прежде всего разобраться, кто кого просит и одно ли здесь ОАО?

В зависимости от того, кто просит и кого, есть варианты.

Если адресат послания - одно ОАО и подписывает бумагу руководитель тех, кто просит,
то не надо вообще никаких уточнений.
***Просим предоставлять файлы с электронными реестрами своевременно.***
И так ясно, кто кого просит.
Если это циркуляр, но подписывает начальник, в принципе можно просто послать предыдущее в несколько адресов, или, если письмо могут получить не только те, кого просят, то 
***Просим ОАО, расположенные на территории КК, предоставлять файлы с электронными реестрами своевременно.*** 
И только если это уходит "наверх", то можно писать в третьем лице.
***Отделение... просит ОАО, расположенные на территории КК, предоставлять файлы с электронными реестрами своевременно.***

Какие еще "ситуации с не предоставлением"?

Answer (score 0):

Как я, с улицы, хотя и на *авто*, понял:

Отделение «Сбербанка России» просит ОАО, расположенные на территории Краснодарского края, исключить предоставление не в полном объёме файлов с электронными реестрами, сформированными по платежам «Сбербанка России».

Comment: Hermit, Ваше "исключить предоставление не в полном объёме" не намного лучше исходного. Имхо.